# The button is not visible which is going to connect another activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

my friends and I are creating an android app for our project and we are new to this and if you think the code is repeated then please post the link.

We have referred from following YouTube video- https://youtu.be/wbsWVtCdiW4

For now we are creating a basic structure for our app. The following is the code entered activity_main.xml which is for button which should connect to other activity but after running the code on emulator and in my phone the app shows a blank screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="157dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="251dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="97dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="323dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:onClick="startdbapp"
    android:text="start db app"
    android:textColor="#F8000000"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

this is the MainActivity.java

```
package com.login.sqlitedemoapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startdbapp(View view) {
        new DbManager(this);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InsertData.class));
    }
}
```

this is my 2nd activity file named activity_insert_data.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".InsertData">

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="242dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="94dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="99dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="587dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter_Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_width="242dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="89dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="194dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="492dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter_Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/t3"
    android:layout_width="241dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="82dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="82dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="396dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter_Course"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="395dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="62dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
    android:onClick="addRecord"
    android:text="Insert Record" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This it the Main activity named InsertData.java

```
 package com.login.sqlitedemoapp;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 public class InsertData extends AppCompatActivity
 {
  EditText t1,t2,t3;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_data);
    t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t2);
    t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t3);
  }

     public void addRecord(View view)
          {
                DbManager db = new DbManager(this);

    String res = db.addRecord(t1.getText().toString(), t2.getText().toString(), 
    t3.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    t1.setText("");
    t2.setText("");
    t3.setText("");
     }
   }
```

Comment: Where do you want to keep the button in activity_main.xml? Like in center of the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a constraint layout. Relative layout is old and most of the developers avoid them. Also, check the constraints of the button.